# Docker container hanging on load with no logging

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm using the [firebase-tools image](https://github.com/AndreySenov/firebase-tools-docker) and initialising it via a docker compose file:

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  firebase-tools-test:
    tty: true
    image: andreysenov/firebase-tools
    ports: 
      - 9099:9099
      - 4000:4000
      - 5000:5000
      - 5001:5001
      - 9199:9199
      - 9005:9005
      - 9000:9000
      - 8085:8085
      - 8080:8080
```

According to the docs localhost:4000 should forward to the firebase UI suite - however it's just sending me to a 404.

The above method has worked for other docker images and I'm not sure where to look to find the issue with this one.

docker logs have no indication of anything, when I run it I get zero logging making me think the container might be hanging.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to enable the UI.

Following the [docs](https://github.com/AndreySenov/firebase-tools-docker/blob/main/doc/guide/running_firebase_emulators.md) you need to execute some commands inside the docker container.

Firstly get a shell inside the container with:

```sh
docker exec -it tfb_firebase-tools-test_1 bash
```

Then from there you need to run `firebase login` and follow the instructions to login.

Then `firebase init emulators` and edit the `firebase.json` file to contain

```json
"ui": {
  "enabled": true,
  "host": "0.0.0.0",  //<--IMPORTANT
  "port": 4000
}
```

Finally `firebase emulators:start` should start the UI.